# Pre-populate cardholder name

Tags: square-checkout

I see it's possible to pre-populate email and shipping address fields, but I'd also like to pre-populate the cardholder name in the Square Checkout payment information section.

The name "Jane Doe" is put in there by default, but that name has some pretty negative connotations. I'd love to replace it with the customer's real name, which I can pass on through JSON.

Can it be done?

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: The post is tagged for Square Checkout, which uses a language agnostic API to generate a credit card checkout page. I'm using PHP  but you can use any language to generate the JSON you send to generate the checkout. I just couldn't find anything in the documentation about doing what I want to do, and Square points people to Stack Overflow to get support.